# How to run SQL transactions using C# (Using TSql110Parser)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have created an ASP.Net C# application to run the SQL server (MSSQL) queries.
The application reads all the user input queries in the text box provided and using the TSql110Parser, it will break down to individual SQL statements.

Its running fine in almost all the cases except when the SQL statements are like the below

```
    DECLARE @user VARCHAR(50)
    SET @user = 'ABC'
    PRINT @user
    SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = @user
```

The execution stops at line 2 and error from SQL server saying that

> Must declare the scalar variable "@user"

even though its defined in the first line.

Then I figured out the below way to run. Adding a BEGIN and END statements.

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @user VARCHAR(50)
    SET @user = 'ABC'
    PRINT @user
    SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = @user
    END
```

But still, then there is a limitation that we won't be able to return the results from the SELECT query.

C# code snippet is below

```
    protected void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (qry.Length > 0)
            {
                using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    dbConnString = dbConnString + "database=" + ddlDBNames.SelectedValue + ";";
                    sqlCon.ConnectionString = dbConnString;
                    sqlCon.Open();              
                    cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
                    IList<ParseError> Errors;
                    var parser = new TSql110Parser(false);
                    var script = parser.Parse(new StringReader(qry), out Errors) as TSqlScript;
                    if (Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        lblErrorMessage.Text = "***** Error: No statements executed *****";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var ts in script.Batches)
                        {
                            foreach (var st in ts.Statements)
                            {
                                q = qry.Substring(st.StartOffset, st.FragmentLength);
                                ExecStatement(st, q);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    protected void ExecStatement(TSqlStatement statement, string qry)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = qry;
            if (statement is SelectStatement)
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                //code to populate the tabular result      
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //code to show the non query execution result
            }
        }
```

Is there any possible way i can run the SQL queries with persistent connection to DB server so that the declaration in the first line will be able to use through out the queries?

The application screenshot below.

[image: WEB Screen Shot]

Comment: how content of `qry` looks like??

Comment: Same as query given on the top

Comment: you need to Exec() the batches, not the statements.

Comment: @devio i need to display the results of each statements in the batches. User will be executing multiple select statements at one go.
Does this Exec() command shows the results of individual statements in the batch? If yes, can you help to elaborate it's usage?

Comment: Screenshot has been added for better understanding

Comment: An alternative is you can receive multiple dataset (from multiple select query) using SqlDataReader

Comment: But what if user enter 'Print 1' ?

Comment: @EagerToLearn it will print 1 on the output messages sections

Comment: @EagerToLearn The screenshot above is a working example. Its returning multiple select results and the print results.
The issue is when we declare a variable and use in the rest of the sql statements. The query i have shared on the top.

Comment: what if you create a temporary stored procedure and put all the statement in it then execute ?

Comment: @EagerToLearn Still there is issue. 
1)The query will only return the end result of the stored procedure
2)This is meant to be used like the SQL Management studio. So every time the query will be dynamic

Comment: 1. As far as I know, Store procedure can return multiple data set.

Comment: 2. "So every time the query will be dynamic " that's why I'm suggesting `temporary stored procedure`

Comment: @EagerToLearn The problem is not with the SQL Query. Its with the C#. We need to run ExecuteNonQuery() function to execute the SP from C# which will return only integer as result.
That is the reason why i have used the TsqlParser to automatically break down the queries to individual statement and then execute. By doing this way, i think the SQL connection always create a new session instead of using a persistent connection

Comment: This is what I have in mind. First in your code behind, if the statement is print, "change" it to select statement, add an extra column to recognize it later. Put them all in an temporary stored procedure (yes you can receive multiple data set from sql with c#, just not with ExecuteNonQuery). A little tricky, but I think it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159376/discussion-between-suraj-kv-and-eagertolearn).

Comment: **TSql110Parser** Is a great tool once I used it to create a app to help devs not to mess with the DB parsing it "testing" the query and organizing a sort of  DB changes repo. I think it cannot be done with **ExecuteNonQuery** I rememeber I also get problems with variables and must get rid of **GO** but it can be done. Will try fo find my old source code.

Comment: @jean That will be great

Answer (score 0):

Use CONTEXT_INFO. It is the connection specific global variable.

Its usage is not simple since it is just a 128 bit value. To set it, run the following code (N = the int you want to store connectionwise)

```
DECLARE @BinVar binary(128);
SET @BinVar = cast(N as binary(128));
set context_info @BinVar
```

You can get the N in subsequent queries by calling the context_info() function. You should convert it with something like this.

```
convert(int, context_info())
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The action required is not on the SQL side. It's on the C# side. The query i have mentioned is just a sample. The query is always dynamic as those will be provided by multiple users.

Comment: You can open a connection in C# code, run the first query. Then, using the same connection object, run other queries and call context_info() in them. Or at least, that is what I understood from " so that the declaration in the first line will be able to use through out the queries?" :)

Comment: The TSQLParser will automatically parse the whole query into multiple SQL statements. So in the first SQL query, the parser will identify it as 4 individual SQL statements, where as in the second (with BEGIN and END), it will identify as a single statement.
And in C# i'm running all the queries within the "using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection())" statement, so ideally it should be using the same set of connection object.

Comment: Screenshot has been added for better understanding